# vim colorschemes don't take effect on startup

Tags: vim, xterm

I have a problem wherein, whenever I start VIM the colorscheme I set on my .vimrc it doesn't take effect upon first running VIM, but then whenever I execute ***:colorscheme 'mycolorscheme'*** the colorscheme is applied.

I'm a beginner in linux, so please bear with me.

I'm just thinking if there is a setting that should be set. Here are the settings I set using xterm.

1. .Xresources

   ```
   *customization: -color
   XTerm*termName: xterm-256color
   ```
2. .xsession

   ```
   if [ -f $HOME/.Xresources ]; then
        xrdb -merge $HOME/.Xresources
   fi
   ```

Upon running `xrdb -query`
Here's the output:

```
*customization:-color
XTerm*termName: xterm-256color
Xft.dpi:    96
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:   rgb
Xft.lcdfilter:  lcddefault
```

Btw, only the colorscheme don't take effect whenever i want to start VIM.
But all mapping and other settings work

**Here's my .vimrc**

```
    "**********************************************"
"           VUNDLE SETTINGS                    "
"**********************************************"

set nocompatible " be iMproved 
filetype off    " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required!
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
filetype plugin indent on " required!

"**********************************************"
"           PLUGINS                            "
"**********************************************"
"EasyMotion
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
"Sparkup
Bundle 'tristen/vim-sparkup'
"Surround
Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'
"CsApprox
Bundle 'godlygeek/csapprox'

"**********************************************"
"           COLOR SCHEMES                      "
"**********************************************"

"   Distinguised
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-distinguished'
"   Github  
Bundle 'endel/vim-github-colorscheme'
"   VividChalk  
Bundle 'tpope/vim-vividchalk'
"   Pyte    
Bundle 'therubymug/vim-pyte'
"   Vibrantink
Bundle 'vim-scripts/vibrantink'

"**********************************************"
"           MAP LEADER                         "
"**********************************************"
let mapleader = ","

"**********************************************"
"           SYNTAX                             "
"**********************************************"
syntax enable

"**********************************************"
"           VIM SCRIPTS                        "
"**********************************************"
if has('gui_running') 
    colorscheme github
else 
    colorscheme pyte
endif

"**********************************************"
"           CUSTOM SETTINGS                    "
"                                              "
"**********************************************"
set hidden

" Show what mode you're currently at
set showmode

" Enable enhanced command line completion
set wildmenu

" Don't redraw while executing macros
set lazyredraw

" Indentation settings (SOFT TABS)"
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set smarttab
set expandtab "enable this to use spaces instead of tabs

" show line number
set nu

" hightlight as you type
set incsearch
" ignore case when searching
set ignorecase

" set statusline
set laststatus=2

"**********************************************"
"       NOTE don't map <c-s> and <c-q>         "
"**********************************************"

"**********************************************"
"           KEYMAPS                            "
"**********************************************"

"*******NORMAL MODE MAPPING********"
"map for editing .vimrc
nnoremap <leader>ev :e $MYVIMRC<cr>
"map for sourcing vimrc
nnoremap <leader>sv :so $MYVIMRC<cr>
"map for switching windows
"_ in this keymap is to jump for a line with a nonblank char
nnoremap <space> <c-w><c-w>_

"*******INSERT MODE Mapping********"
"map for escape while in insert mode
inoremap <leader>; <esc>
"map for ins-completion
inoremap <leader>x <c-x>

"*********COMMAND MODE Mappings*******
"exit out of command line mode
cnoremap <leader>; <c-c>
```

**Edit**

It doesn't work whatever terminal emulator i used. Either gnome-terminal or xterm.
 It seems like the colorsheme is indeed loaded. Upon first loading, Typing :colorscheme reports the correct colorscheme which i set on my .vimrc. But it doesn't take effect the first time. I have to either type on VIM

```
:colo 'colorschemename'
```

or source it again to activate the colorscheme using

```
:so $MYVIMRC
```

But after exiting VIM, the colorscheme again doesn't take effect but it is loaded upon starting VIM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works on gvim
but not on terminal :(

Answer (score 4):

Put a colorscheme directive in your ~/.vimrc file

For example

```
colorscheme evening
```

**Update1:**

With your ~/.vimrc and installation of [Vundle](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3458) I reproduced your problem.
Add

```
set t_Co=256
colorscheme evening
```

at the end of your ~/.vimrc and see if this works for you.

You can see also http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal

Comment: Can I see your ~/.vimrc ?

Comment: i've edited the question. I've added my .vimrc

Comment: Maybe you can backup your ~/.vimrc and then put only the `colorscheme evening` just to ensure that  the problem relates to the ~/.vimrc file.

Comment: yes, something's wrong with my .vimrc

i've only use colorscheme evening

and it works

Comment: only the default colorschemes work upon starting VIM
though all colorschemes work when executing them using :colorscheme

`echo $TERM "outputs xterm-256color`
AND
`set t_Co=256`

i still can't make it work :(

Comment: i've tried setting. `sest t_Co=256` on .vimrc but still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I think i have to answer my own question. I'm really on despair so i went on to removing the plugins one by one through **BundleClean!** in **Vundle** to check if there's any plugin misbehaving.

It was not a problem with my .vimrc after all. It was a conflict with **EasyMotion** and **CSApprox** plugins.

I had my **EasyMotion** configuration before **CSApprox** on **Vundle** I followed the instructions on this one.

https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion/issues/55

Here's another one that might help others with the same issues as mine.

https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion/issues/39